# How to set color of NSPopupButton Menu Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

How do you set the color of an NSPopupButton Menu Item?

Comment: Note that `setAttributedTitle` was introduced in 10.3, which was only available on 2003, which is *later* than the email exchanges you referred to. So that was the only thing they could do.

Comment: excellent! slightly modified it also works well for adding a simple image to each menu item.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that it seems you cannot style the highlighted state with 'inverse' text with this approach.  I've been trying to figure out a way to do this without going custom views in a `NSMenu`.  So far no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching online, I only found [a really hacked, contorted answer to this question](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/58379-changing-the-text-color-of-an-nsmenuitem-in-an-nspopupbutton.html), which can be answered more elegantly like so:

```
NSArray *itemArray = [scalePopup itemArray];
int i;
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary
                            dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            [NSFont systemFontOfSize: [NSFont systemFontSize]],
                            NSFontAttributeName, nil];

for (i = 0; i < [itemArray count]; i++) {
    NSMenuItem *item = [itemArray objectAtIndex:i];
    
    NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
             initWithString:[item title]
             attributes:attributes];
    
    [item setAttributedTitle:as];
}
```

Comment: That's not how this site works. If you want to answer your own question, you're supposed to pretend you're on Jeopardy and phrase it in the form of a question. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Comment: Oddly, the font size is still too small. To get a better match with regular items I had to use `[NSFont menuFontOfSize:14.0]`.

Comment: I appreciated the answer nevertheless - it saved me time. Rules are made to be broken occasionally :-)

Comment: I edited this to be in question/answer form.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a same problem.

To preserve original text attributes,
my solution is here:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
NSAttributedString *cellStr = [[self.popup cell] attributedTitle];
NSMutableDictionary *cellAttr = [[cellStr attributesAtIndex:range.location effectiveRange:&range] mutableCopy];
[cellAttr setObject:[NSColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

NSArray *menuItems = [self.popup itemArray];    
for (NSMenuItem *menu in menuItems ) {
    NSString *orgTitle = [menu title];
    NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:orgTitle attributes:cellAttr];

    [menuItem setAttributedTitle:title];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.5**

Assign an attributed string to the menu item.  For example, I change the title color by assigning a bold green attributed string if the item was previously selected.

I have a property that I set for the previously selected title, so I can easily remove the attributed string if another title is selected.

```
var previousTitle: String = ""
```

Then in my method, I do the following

```
if !previousTitle.isEmpty {
    // Remove the previously assigned attributed title
    myPopUpButton.selectItem(withTitle: previousTitle)
    myPopUpButton.selectedItem?.attributedTitle = nil
}
previousTitle = <some previously selected title>
myPopUpButton.selectItem(withTitle: previousTitle)
let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13).bold
let foreground = NSColor.green
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: previousTitle, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: foreground])
myPopUpButton.selectedItem?.attributedTitle = attrString
```