# Objective-C, NSPopMenuButton & NSMenu Color

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsmenu, nspopupbutton

I have an `NSPopMenuButton` which is connected to an `NSMenu` in the standard way. I tried sub-classing both in an attempt to change the background color of the menu itself. I'm clearly not doing something correctly, so any advice would be helpful.

Tried (NSPopUpButton) `customPopUpButton.m`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    [[NSColor grayColor] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

}
```

Which gave me:
[image: not good]
I'd actually rather it be like:
[image: better]

I tried creating another class to override `NSPopUpButtonCell` as suggested by another answer, but I must not know how to implement it correctly as it seems to have no effect other than what the code above does.

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    [[NSColor grayColor] set];
    NSRectFill(cellFrame);

    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];

}
```

Something to note is that my deployment target is macOS 10.11 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the background color of an NSPopupButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222205/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-an-nspopupbutton)

Comment: See [How to set color of NSPopupButton Menu Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731982/how-to-set-color-of-nspopupbutton-menu-item)

Comment: @Willeke, I tried that actually but I don't know how to properly implement the suggestion in the answer. I added a new sub-class to `NSPopUpButtonCell` and put the method in, but it seems to do nothing that the original code I posted does.

Answer (score 1):

Your customized `NSPopUpButton` drawing is filling the entire drawing area with color. Default title drawing is missing (under the filled color).

Try customizing `NSPopUpButtonCell drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView`.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to implement this? I tried and nothing happens other than what already is taking place.

Comment: @Joe Habadas,When you used customized nspopupbuttoncell,did you remove customization done for nspopupbutton?

Comment: I finally got the NSPopUpButtonCell to show the color correctly with the text after removing the customization in NSPopUpButton, but the NSPopUpButtonCell did not colorize the NSMenu items, so I guess that is something else I need to subclass? In the meantime I selected "Dark Aqua" for the View's Appearance, which worked. I would like to do that programmatically though if possible.

Comment: @JoeHabadas, You can set the appearance programmatically;            [someView setAppearance:[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua]];